# Logstash grok filter - name fields dynamically

Tags: logstash

I've got log lines in the following format and want to extract fields:

```
[field1: content1] [field2: content2] [field3: content3] ...
```

I neither know the field names, nor the number of fields.

I tried it with backreferences and the sprintf format but got no results:

```
match => [ "message", "(?:\[(\w+): %{DATA:\k<-1>}\])+" ] # not working
match => [ "message", "(?:\[%{WORD:fieldname}: %{DATA:%{fieldname}}\])+" ] # not working
```

This seems to work for only one field but not more:

```
match => [ "message", "(?:\[%{WORD:field}: %{DATA:content}\] ?)+" ]
add_field => { "%{field}" => "%{content}" }
```

The kv filter is also not appropriate because the content of the fields may contain whitespaces.

Is there any plugin / strategy to fix this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Logstash Ruby Plugin can help you. :)

Here is the configuration:

```
input {
    stdin {}
}

filter {
    ruby {
        code => "
            fieldArray = event['message'].split('] [')
            for field in fieldArray
                field = field.delete '['
                field = field.delete ']'
                result = field.split(': ')
                event[result[0]] = result[1]
            end
        "
    }
}

output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

With your logs:

```
[field1: content1] [field2: content2] [field3: content3]
```

This is the output:

```
{
   "message" => "[field1: content1] [field2: content2] [field3: content3]",
  "@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => "2014-07-07T08:49:28.543Z",
      "host" => "abc",
    "field1" => "content1",
    "field2" => "content2",
    "field3" => "content3"
}
```

I have try with 4 fields, it also works.

Please note that the `event` in the ruby code is logstash event. You can use it to get all your event field such as `message, @timestamp` etc.

Enjoy it!!!

Answer (score 6):

I found another way using regex:

```
ruby {
    code => "
        fields = event['message'].scan(/(?<=\[)\w+: .*?(?=\](?: |$))/)
        for field in fields
            field = field.split(': ')
            event[field[0]] = field[1]
        end
    "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old post, but I just came across it today, so I thought I'd offer an alternate method. Please note that, as a rule, I would almost always use a ruby filter, as suggested in either of the two previous answers. However, I thought I would offer this as an alternative.

If there is a fixed number of fields or a maximum number of fields (i.e., there may be fewer than three fields, but there will never be more than three fields), this can be done with a combination of `grok` and `mutate` filters, as well.

```
# Test message is: `[fieldname: value]`
# Store values in [@metadata] so we don't have to explicitly delete them.
grok {
    match => {
        "[message]" => [
            "\[%{DATA:[@metadata][_field_name_01]}:\s+%{DATA:[@metadata][_field_value_01]}\]( \[%{DATA:[@metadata][_field_name_02]}:\s+%{DATA:[@metadata][_field_value_02]}\])?( \[%{DATA:[@metadata][_field_name_03]}:\s+%{DATA:[@metadata][_field_value_03]}\])?"
        ]
    }
}

# Rename the fieldname, value combinations. I.e., if the following data is in the message:
#
#     [foo: bar]
#
# It will be saved in the elasticsearch output as:
#
#    {"foo":"bar"}
#
mutate {
    rename => {
        "[@metadata][_field_value_01]" => "[%{[@metadata][_field_name_01]}]"
        "[@metadata][_field_value_02]" => "[%{[@metadata][_field_name_02]}]"
        "[@metadata][_field_value_03]" => "[%{[@metadata][_field_name_03]}]"
    }
    tag_on_failure => []
}
```

For those who may not be as familiar with regex, the captures in `()?` are optional regex matches, meaning that if there is no match, the expression won't fail. The `tag_on_failure => []` option in the `mutate` filter ensures that no error will be appended to `tags` if one of the renames fails because there was no data to capture and, as a result, there is no field to rename.