# logstash, generate multiple fields from multiple match

Tags: logstash, key-value

I would like to industrialise the creation of fields based on a multiple match regex.
My log message has this format:

```
TIMESTAMP| KEY1 VALUE1: KEY2 VALUE2: KEY3 VALUE3: description
```

I would like to know if there is a way to create thanks to a generic match the fields:

```
KEY1=VALUE1, KEY2=VALUE2, KEY3=VALUE3
```

The goal is to have a generic logstash filter. If I had a new key value in the log, I will not have to change the logstash configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [kv](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/kv) filter that can parse key=value type of things automatically.  If you want to parse in the format above, you'll need to resort to ruby code such as in this question/answer: [Logstash grok filter - name fields dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605331/logstash-grok-filter-name-fields-dynamically)

Comment: Thank you the solution fits my need