# How to remove all fields with NULL value in Logstash filter

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, checkpoint

I am reading checkpoint log file with csv format with logstash
and some fields have null value.

i want to remove all fields with null value.

i can not foresee exactly which fields(keys) will have null value because i have 150 columns in the csv file and i dont want check each one of them.

is it possible to do a dynamic filter in logstash that will remove any fields with null value?

my logstash configuration file look like that:

```
input {
  stdin { tags => "checkpoint" } 
   file {
   type => "file-input"
   path =>  "D:\Browser Downloads\logstash\logstash-1.4.2\bin\checkpoint.csv"
   sincedb_path => "D:\Browser Downloads\logstash\logstash-1.4.2\bin\sincedb-access2"
   start_position => "beginning"
   tags => ["checkpoint","offline"]
  }
}
filter {
 if "checkpoint" in [tags] {
        csv {
        columns => ["num","date","time","orig","type","action","alert","i/f_name","i/f_dir","product","Internal_CA:","serial_num:","dn:","sys_message:","inzone","outzone","rule","rule_uid","rule_name","service_id","src","dst","proto","service","s_port","dynamic object","change type","message_info","StormAgentName","StormAgentAction","TCP packet out of state","tcp_flags","xlatesrc","xlatedst","NAT_rulenum","NAT_addtnl_rulenum","xlatedport","xlatesport","fw_message","ICMP","ICMP Type","ICMP Code","DCE-RPC Interface UUID","rpc_prog","log_sys_message","scheme:","Validation log:","Reason:","Serial num:","Instruction:","fw_subproduct","vpn_feature_name","srckeyid","dstkeyid","user","methods:","peer gateway","IKE:","CookieI","CookieR","msgid","IKE notification:","Certificate DN:","IKE IDs:","partner","community","Session:","L2TP:","PPP:","MAC:","OM:","om_method:","assigned_IP:","machine:","reject_category","message:","VPN internal source IP","start_time","connection_uid","encryption failure:","vpn_user","Log ID","message","old IP","old port","new IP","new port","elapsed","connectivity_state","ctrl_category","description","description ","severity","auth_status","identity_src","snid","src_user_name","endpoint_ip","src_machine_name","src_user_group","src_machine_group","auth_method","identity_type","Authentication trial","roles","dst_user_name","dst_machine_name","spi","encryption fail reason:","information","error_description","domain_name","termination_reason","duration"]
      #  remove_field => [ any fields with null value] how to do it please 
        separator => "|"
        }
    # drop csv header
        if [num] == "num" and [date] == "date" and [time] == "time" and [orig] == "orig" {
        drop { }
    }
    }
  }

}
output {
   stdout {
    codec => rubydebug 
  }
   file {
      path => "output.txt"
   }
```

HERE I ATTACH SOME LOGS EXAMPLE:

```
num|date|time|orig|type|action|alert|i/f_name|i/f_dir|product|Internal_CA:|serial_num:|dn:|sys_message:|inzone|outzone|rule|rule_uid|rule_name|service_id|src|dst|proto|service|s_port|dynamic object|change type|message_info|StormAgentName|StormAgentAction|TCP packet out of state|tcp_flags|xlatesrc|xlatedst|NAT_rulenum|NAT_addtnl_rulenum|xlatedport|xlatesport|fw_message|ICMP|ICMP Type|ICMP Code|DCE-RPC Interface UUID|rpc_prog|log_sys_message|scheme:|Validation log:|Reason:|Serial num:|Instruction:|fw_subproduct|vpn_feature_name|srckeyid|dstkeyid|user|methods:|peer gateway|IKE:|CookieI|CookieR|msgid|IKE notification:|Certificate DN:|IKE IDs:|partner|community|Session:|L2TP:|PPP:|MAC:|OM:|om_method:|assigned_IP:|machine:|reject_category|message:|VPN internal source IP|start_time|connection_uid|encryption failure:|vpn_user|Log ID|message|old IP|old port|new IP|new port|elapsed|connectivity_state|ctrl_category|description|description |severity|auth_status|identity_src|snid|src_user_name|endpoint_ip|src_machine_name|src_user_group|src_machine_group|auth_method|identity_type|Authentication trial|roles|dst_user_name|dst_machine_name|spi|encryption fail reason:|information|error_description|domain_name|termination_reason|duration
0|8Jun2012|16:33:35|10.0.0.1|log|keyinst||daemon|inbound|VPN-1 & FireWall-1|started|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
 1|8Jun2012|16:36:34|10.0.0.1|log|keyinst||daemon|inbound|VPN-1 & FireWall-1|started|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
 2|8Jun2012|16:52:39|10.0.0.1|log|keyinst||daemon|inbound|VPN-1 & FireWall-1|Certificate initialized|86232|CN=fw-KO,O=sc-KO.KO.dc.obn8cx|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
 3|8Jun2012|16:52:39|10.0.0.1|log|keyinst||daemon|inbound|VPN-1 & FireWall-1|Initiated certificate is now valid|86232|CN=fw-KO,O=sc-KO.KO.dc.obn8cx|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
 4|8Jun2012|16:55:44|10.0.0.1|log|keyinst||daemon|inbound|VPN-1 & FireWall-1|Issued empty CRL 1|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
20|8Jun2012|16:58:28|10.0.0.1|log|accept||eth1|inbound|VPN-1 & FireWall-1|||||Internal|External|1|{2A42C8CD-148D-4809-A480-3171108AD6C7}||domain-udp|192.168.100.1|198.32.64.12|udp|53|1036|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Ruby` filter can meet your requirement.

```
input {
        stdin {
        }
}

filter {
        csv {
                columns => ["num","date","time","orig","type","action","alert","i/f_name","i/f_dir","product","Internal_CA:","serial_num:","dn:","sys_message:","inzone","outzone","rule","rule_uid","rule_name","service_id","src","dst","proto","service","s_port","dynamic object","change type","message_info","StormAgentName","StormAgentAction","TCP packet out of state","tcp_flags","xlatesrc","xlatedst","NAT_rulenum","NAT_addtnl_rulenum","xlatedport","xlatesport","fw_message","ICMP","ICMP Type","ICMP Code","DCE-RPC Interface UUID","rpc_prog","log_sys_message","scheme:","Validation log:","Reason:","Serial num:","Instruction:","fw_subproduct","vpn_feature_name","srckeyid","dstkeyid","user","methods:","peer gateway","IKE:","CookieI","CookieR","msgid","IKE notification:","Certificate DN:","IKE IDs:","partner","community","Session:","L2TP:","PPP:","MAC:","OM:","om_method:","assigned_IP:","machine:","reject_category","message:","VPN internal source IP","start_time","connection_uid","encryption failure:","vpn_user","Log ID","message","old IP","old port","new IP","new port","elapsed","connectivity_state","ctrl_category","description","description ","severity","auth_status","identity_src","snid","src_user_name","endpoint_ip","src_machine_name","src_user_group","src_machine_group","auth_method","identity_type","Authentication trial","roles","dst_user_name","dst_machine_name","spi","encryption fail reason:","information","error_description","domain_name","termination_reason","duration"]
                separator => "|"
        }
        ruby {
                code => "
                        hash = event.to_hash
                        hash.each do |k,v|
                                if v == nil
                                        event.remove(k)
                                end
                        end
                "
        }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

You can use ruby plugin to filter all the field with `nil` value (null in Ruby)

**Updated:**

This is my environment: Windows server 2008 and Logstash 1.4.1.
Your logs sample is work at me! I have updated the configuration, input and output.

Input

```
2|8Jun2012|16:52:39|10.0.0.1|log|keyinst||daemon|inbound|VPN-1 & FireWall-1|Certificate initialized|86232|CN=fw-KO,O=sc-KO.KO.dc.obn8cx|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

Output:

```
{
        "@version" => "1",
      "@timestamp" => "2015-03-12T00:30:34.123Z",
            "host" => "BENLIM",
             "num" => "2",
            "date" => "8Jun2012",
            "time" => "16:52:39",
            "orig" => "10.0.0.1",
            "type" => "log",
          "action" => "keyinst",
        "i/f_name" => "daemon",
         "i/f_dir" => "inbound",
         "product" => "VPN-1 & FireWall-1",
    "Internal_CA:" => "Certificate initialized",
     "serial_num:" => "86232",
             "dn:" => "CN=fw-KO,O=sc-KO.KO.dc.obn8cx"
}
```

Comment: Hello Ben thanks for helping me, i am testing you ruby answer but in the output to file the null fields still exist...

Comment: Can I know the field value is "nil" or "null"? If you want to remove the field with value "null", in the ruby code you want to use "if v== 'null '"

Comment: this not working when your logstash output is file or elasticsearch

Comment: But it's worked on me in either stdout or file. Can you provide your log sample?

Comment: Hi Ben and 10x for helping me. i update my question and provided a log example

Comment: I have update the answer. Your logs is worked at me. Maybe you have try to figure out other problem. You can  use my config and test again.

Comment: can you try add file to ouput section. please tell me if there is  null value in the  output file

Comment: Yes! I also use the file output. The null value field will be eliminated

Comment: Ok Ben your answer work great, i had a mistake in my config file because that in my filter section i use  remove_field => [ ] on the csv plugin. so its  ignore the removed fields from ruby plugin

Comment: There is also an option in the csv filter named skip_empty_columns (at least there is now) - but the ruby was inventive. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the [`skip_empty_columns`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html#plugins-filters-csv-skip_empty_columns) option of the [`csv`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html) filter - was really helpful in my use case. :)

Usage:

```
skip_empty_columns => true
```

Comment: Wow! That worked brilliantly! So nice and simple.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove all null, blank, and empty fields recursively (`0` and `false` remain), this function might be able to help. It uses the Ruby filter in Logstash. It's by no means elegant, but seems to work pretty effectively.

```
filter {
    ruby {
        init => "
            def Compact(key)
                modifiedKey = nil
                parentKey = nil

                if key.kind_of?(String)
                    if key.start_with?('[')
                        modifiedKey = key
                    else
                        modifiedKey = key.sub( /([^\[^\]]*)/, '[\1]')
                    end

                parentKey = modifiedKey.sub(/\[[^\[]+\]$/, '') unless modifiedKey.sub(/\[[^\[]+\]$/, '').strip.empty?
                end

                unless modifiedKey.nil?
                    if event.get(modifiedKey).is_a?(Enumerable) &&
                    (event.get(modifiedKey).nil? || event.get(modifiedKey).empty?)
                         event.remove(modifiedKey)
                    elsif event.get(modifiedKey).to_s.strip.empty? || event.get(modifiedKey).nil?
                         event.remove(modifiedKey)
                     end

                    if !parentKey.nil? && event.get(parentKey).is_a?(Enumerable) &&
                    (event.get(parentKey).nil? || event.get(parentKey).empty?)
                        event.remove(parentKey)
                    end
                end

               if key == event.to_hash ||
               event.get((modifiedKey ? modifiedKey : '')).is_a?(Enumerable)
                   key = event.get(modifiedKey) unless modifiedKey.nil?
                   key.each{ |k|
                      Compact(%{#{modifiedKey ? modifiedKey : ''}[#{k.first}]}) if k.is_a?(Enumerable)
                   }
               end

               rescue Exception => e
                   puts %{ruby_exception_#{__method__.to_s} - #{e}}
           end
      "

     code => "
         Compact(event.to_hash)
     "
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ruby {
            init => "
                def removeEmptyField(event,h,name)
                    h.each do |k,v|
                            if (v.is_a?(Hash) || v.is_a?(Array)) && v.to_s != '{}'
                                removeEmptyField(event,v,String.new(name.to_s) << '[' << k.to_s << ']')
                            else
                            if v == '' || v.to_s == '{}'
                                event.remove(String.new(name.to_s) << '[' << k.to_s << ']')
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            "
            code => "
                removeEmptyField event,event.to_hash,''
            "
    }
```

Comment: I can confirm that the code above does what is expected – remove fields with null value. Using logstash 6.8.1. I've enhanced it a bit to remove fields with "-" value as well. Just make the second `if` line to look like: `if v == '' || v.to_s == '{}' || v == '-'`

Comment: Actually, to remove fields with `null` value, one needs to add `|| v == nil` as well.

Answer (score 0):

To do things this dynamically, you'll want to use the ruby{} filter.  There's some good sample code [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605331/logstash-grok-filter-name-fields-dynamically).

Comment: Hi Alain thnks for helping me, i am tring to use ruby filter but i am new to ruby.... and the result output to my file still got a null fields, i will be a glad to get code example to my specific problem that i can test