# Logstash filter that drops events when something is null

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

So I wrote a filter to drop any event that has a certain field with a value of null:

```
 filter {
    if[type] == "flow" and [packet_source][ip] == "" {
            drop { }
    }
}
```

However, this does not work. Does anyone have any idea why? The names of the parameters are correct

Logstash version 5.2

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28959437/4604579

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your filter is checking that `[packet_source][ip] == ""` exists and is *not* null.

Not sure what `[type] == "flow"` is, but I think you want

```
filter {
  if[type] == "flow" and ("" not in [packet_source][ip]) {
    drop { }
  }
}
```

You can also use `!("" in [packet_source][ip])` or `!([packet_source][ip] == "")`

However, per the documentation, there’s currently no way to differentiate between a field that doesn’t exist versus a field that’s simply false.

You can reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html

Comment: Thank you! I got confused by a couple other forum posts that I saw, but what you said there works. 

`[type] == "flow" `

Is netflow data collected by [Packetbeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/packetbeat)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @cattastrophe's answer, try this as well:

```
if "flow" in [type] and "" in [packet_source][ip]{      
    drop { }        
}
```

**AND**

```
if[type] == "flow" and [packet_source][ip] == 'null'{ <-- please try with double quotes around null as well
        drop { }        
}
```