# Logstash split field into multiple fields or split array into multiple fields

Tags: arrays, split, logstash, translate, logstash-configuration

I have a .txt file I am parsing that has multiple values for one field, inputFields.

```
INPUT
@07  
@09
@11
```

I can successfully grok, mutate, and split inputFields into an array containing all the values.

pattern.txt

```
INPUT_FIELDS (?<inputFields>INPUT\s*(@\d*)*)
```

logstash.conf

```
grok {
        match => [ "message", "%{INPUT_FIELDS}"]
    }
mutate {
        gsub => ["inputFields", "INPUT\s*@", ""]
        split => ["inputFields", "@"]
    }
```

Gives me this output

```
"inputFields" => [
  [0] "07",
  [1] "09",
  [2] "11"
 ]
```

The problem is, I want to use the translate plugin, which does not work on array values.

I would like to split this array into multiple fields in the same document.  Preferably, each field would be labeled "input_field[i].

For example:

```
"input_field1" => "07",
"input_field2" => "09", 
"input_field3" => "11"
```

I have tried tailoring this response [Logstash grok filter - name fields dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605331/logstash-grok-filter-name-fields-dynamically), which uses Ruby, to fit my needs, but it splits the fields into multiple documents, or keeps them in the same field without splitting.

Could someone lend me a hand with the Ruby code, or split plugin config?

**Update**
I was able to create separate events for the input fields, but I am unable to create the fields with an index.  I must use the field itself to dynamically create a new field.

I removed the mutate { split }, and split it with Ruby instead.

Here is my new code

```
ruby {
        code => "
            inputs = event['inputFields'].split('@')
            for input in inputs
                event['inputField_' + input] = input
            end
        "
    }
```

This creates

```
"inputField_07" => "07"
"inputField_09" => "09"
"inputfield_11" => "11"
```

I would still take any advice about how to change these to inputField_[index].  I tried using different variables in Ruby, but I cannot add them to the new field name.

Dynamically naming the fields has created a new problem.  I would like to use the translate plugin, but you must select a specific field for translate to look at.  Since the fields I created all have different names, I cannot point to any of them.  I have tried using regular expressions to match the field, but it is not supported by translate.

Suggestions??

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve your goal of splitting into new fields without ruby code, in this way:

```
mutate {
    # split the field on ::
    split => ["api_class" , "::"]
    # save the last element of the array as the api_method.
    add_field => ["api_method", "%{[api_class][-1]}" ]
}
```

I found this answer myself on [this page](https://gist.github.com/human39/8b80d51a75c99e64eb42).

Good luck!